# Arranging Div Tags left, center & right

Tags: php, html

I have a Three bar's in my website. Left, center & Right [Please click here to see](http://www.fedri.com). The problem is that, the code for left and Center bar are present in Header and the right bar code is present in footer of the website.

If the webpage loads, its load left and center first and it takes time to load the right side bar. I am trying to keep right side bar also in header. I am not getting it. I just copy the code of right side bar from footer to header but its not working. If I do like this only left and right bar is on there place but the center bar is going below the both.

My Header Code

```
<div id="main-cont">
    <!-- IF S_IN_TOPIC -->
        <div id="main-cont-left" style="width:100%;">
    <!-- ELSE -->
        <div id="main-cont-left">
    <!-- ENDIF -->
    <!-- IF not (S_IN_UCP or S_IN_MCP or S_CLUBS ) -->
    <!-- INCLUDE sidebar_left.html -->
    <!-- IF S_IN_TOPIC -->
        <div id="main-cont-left-main" style="width:720px;">
    <!-- ELSE -->
        <div id="main-cont-left-main">
    <!-- ENDIF -->  
    <!-- ELSE -->
    </div></div><div id="page-body">
    <!-- ENDIF -->
```

The COde in my Footer is

```
<!-- IF not (S_IN_UCP or S_IN_MCP) -->
</div>
<br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
<!-- IF not S_IN_TOPIC -->
    <!-- INCLUDE sidebar_right.html -->
<!-- ENDIF -->
<br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
<!-- ELSE -->
</div>
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

Please provide me the code I shall keep in my header so that both the all the bar's to load at the same time.

Comment: According to your page, you have all those columns inside div with id page-body. So, nothing in header as it seems, what do you want to change?

Comment: Do you want main-cont-right to main-cont-left? inside one div?

Comment: everything is fine, but its taking time to load the sidebar_right.html as it is located in the footer. I want to shift this code to header.

Answer (score 0):

Header

> ```
> <div id="main-cont">
> <!-- IF S_IN_TOPIC -->
>     <div id="main-cont-left" style="width:100%;">
> <!-- ELSE -->
>     <div id="main-cont-left">
> <!-- ENDIF -->
> <!-- IF not (S_IN_UCP or S_IN_MCP or S_CLUBS ) -->
> <!-- INCLUDE sidebar_left.html -->
> <!-- IF S_IN_TOPIC -->
>     <div id="main-cont-left-main" style="width:720px;">
> <!-- ELSE -->
>     <div id="main-cont-left-main">
>     <!-- INCLUDE sidebar_right.html -->
> <!-- ENDIF -->  
> <!-- ELSE -->
> </div></div><div id="page-body">
> <!-- ENDIF -->
> ```

Footer

> ```
> <!-- IF not (S_IN_UCP or S_IN_MCP) -->
> </div>
> <br style="clear:both;" />
> </div>
> <br style="clear:both;" />
> </div>
> <!-- ELSE -->
> </div>
> <!-- ENDIF -->
> ```

as the template include it in IF not (S_IN_UCP or S_IN_MCP) & IF not S_IN_TOPIC i just add the include call in the corresponding bloc of the header.

It will normally work (as the code provide load the left one same way just 3 line upper) but since i have no way to test the template out of his system ...

Hope it help

Comment: I dont know why, but its not working. How can i give you the files to test.??